# IDEA Android plugin: where is blueprint view?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

The designer of android studio supports a mode called Blueprint View, as shown in https://developer.android.com/studio/write/layout-editor.html#change-appearance:

[image: Blueprint buttons in Android Studio]

However, these buttons are missing in the latest Intellij IDEA version (2016.2.5) using the Android plugin (i.e. using IDEA and not Android Studio):

[image: Missing buttons in Idea]

Is there a way to get blueprint view with rulers etc in IDEA?

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware that adding Android plugin to Intellij will **NOT** turn it into Android Studio. Certain features are only available in Android Studio only for now.